# RelativeLayout, Unable to resolve id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

i was trying to layout views within `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/upperView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/bottomView"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this id is not recognized by android:

```
 android:layout_below="@id/bottomView"
```

because i defined the `@+id/bottomView"` after its call, but sometimes **the sort matter** to draw who over who, i can solve it from the code, but how fix it within XML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your layout when define:

```
@+id/bottomView"
```

The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file)

When referencing an Android resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol, but must add the android package namespace (Ref.1)

**So, change your xml layout like that**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:text="DownTextView" 
        android:id="@+id/upperView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottomView">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:text="UpTextView" 
        android:id="@id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Reference**:1 [Android Layout ID Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

Comment: Your issue is "Unable to resolve id" so i think change order of "@+id/bottomView" and "@id/bottomView" can solver your problem. Sorry if not correct for your question.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it, just add `+` before `id` keyword in your layout xml

Comment: The + needs to come before id - `"@+id/the_id"`

Answer (score 0):

How can you do upper view to be below bottom view, logically is inconsistent to me?

You should do otherwise. In the `bottomview` you add `android:layout_below="@id/upperview"`

Since bottom is below something.

Comment: in my question i told the sort matter to the design, so i cant change the sort, because the last view draws over before view, and i need that

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create bottomView, and then use the layout_below, because android / java create things in the order, what in you made them. Hope it helps.